# Separation of Areas ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

how can I handle my ASP.NET MVC areas, that I'm able to reuse them in different projects?

I'm aware about that there exists many articles to separate areas into an own assembly, but isn't there a nicer solution out? All guides I found doesn't look like a "standard" Microsoft supported way.

Comment: Hey Patrik this is a question more suitable for the programmers stack exchange. Thanks

Comment: Microsoft does not support a standard way to separate areas.  Any solution has to be developed third party.  The closest thing is portable areas from MVC Contrib, but this is being phased out in support of using Nuget to distribute packages of areas...